# How to get value of array key from query in golang

Tags: arrays, url, go

I have this query

```
site.com/?status[0]=1&status[1]=2&status[1]=3&name=John
```

I want to get all the values of **status** key like

> 1, 2, 3

I tried something like this

```
for _, status:= range r.URL.Query()["status"] {
    fmt.Println(status)
}
```

but it only works if the query is without array key: `site.com/?status=1&status=2&status=3&name=John`

Comment: can you put status value to like this one instead? like `site.com?&status=1,2,3`?

Comment: I can't because my frontend is using a react js package component which convert the selection query to be `?status[0]=1&status[1]=2&status[1]=3`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One approach is to loop over the possible values and append to a slice as you go:

```
r.ParseForm()  // parses request body and query and stores result in r.Form
var a []string
for i := 0; ; i++ {
    key := fmt.Sprintf("status[%d]", i)
    values := r.Form[key] // form values are a []string
    if len(values) == 0 {
        // no more values
        break
    }
    a = append(a, values[i])
    i++
}
```

If you have control over the query string, then use this format:

```
 site.com/?status=1&status=2&status=3&name=John
```

and get status values using:

```
 r.ParseForm()
 a := r.Form["status"]  // a is []string{"1", "2", "3"}
```